# Link design within the new unregistered user inbox/achievements dialogue looks weird

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, top-bar, unregistered-users

> [image: new-inbox-dialogue]

That looks weird.

The `log in` is hyperlinked, but `sign up` is not and instead, there's a big blue button saying `sign up` underneath it. Why  not just have 2 buttons? Or hyperlink both? Something like:

[image: improved-example-1]
[image: improved-example-2]

---

By the way, the hyperlinked version is what's done in mobile web:

[image: mobile-web-example]

So you could argue that this is being inconsistent between the web version and mobile version ;)